# How to get accumulated value of TextBox in WFA (.NET)?

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a program that requires about three textbox values. Those values will then get added to display their total. Example:

```
int input1 = 1;
int input2 = 1;
int input3 = 1;

totalInput = input1 + input2 + input3;
```

As previously mentioned, they get added.

```
1st run: 3; // with values of 1, 1, 1
2nd run: 6; // with values of 2, 2, 2
3rd run: 9; // with values of 3, 3, 3
```

Good so far

However, I'm trying to create a running total to display it in my form. I do that by using the operator of `+=` . Take a look in the cove below:

```
ticketsSoldTextBox.Text += totalInput;
```

However, this keeps concatenating the values instead of adding them.

```
1st run: 3; // with values of 1, 1, 1
2nd run: 36; // with values of 2, 2, 2
3rd run: 369; // with values of 3, 3, 3
```

The output that I'm expecting in the totalInput TextBox should be the addition of `3 + 6 + 9` which equals to `18`.

Does it makes sense? I'm kinda getting frustrated with this already?  Do I need to create a loop for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating strings by `ticketsSoldTextBox.Text += totalInput;`

Cast`ticketsSoldTextBox.Text` to an integer and then add them together.

```
    private static void Sum()
    {
        string input1 = "1";
        string input2 = "2";
        string input3 = "3";
        // Int32.Parse(ticketsSoldTextBox.Text)
        int sum =Int32.Parse(input1) + Int32.Parse(input2) + Int32.Parse(input3);
        Console.WriteLine(sum); // print 6 in the console
    }
```

**Error handling also required to avoid Null exception error**